# How to Deserialize JSON Array?

Tags: java, json, cxf, jax-rs, jackson

I'm using Jackson within CXF to serialize/deserialize data. Unfortunately, I am having difficulty configuring CXF/Jackson to deserialize a JSON array. I'd appreciate help in resolving the issue.

Up to this point most of the json data has been in object format, i.e.

`{ "objectCollection": [ {...}, {...}, {...}... ] }`

However, the json data in question is of the form:

`[ {...}, {...}, {...} ]`

The web service endpoint expects a "GroupsDto" object (see following)
that has a single property -- a collection of groups, which is
transmitted via the JSON array.

```
@PATH(...)
public Response createGroups(GroupsDto groups) {
...
}
```

I added @JsonDeserialize as follows to the GroupsDto collection property, but it does NOT work. I continue to get: "Can not deserialize instance of GroupsDto out of START_ARRAY token"

```
public class GroupsDto {

       private Collection<GroupDto> groups;

       /**
        * @return the groups
        */
       @XmlElement(name="group")
       @JsonDeserialize(contentAs=GroupDto.class)
       public Collection<GroupDto> getGroups() {
               return groups;
       }
...
}
```

Comment: Check this question [Jackson - reading a JSON array with Robospice using loadDataFromNetwork() method][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792702/jackson-reading-a-json-array-with-robospice-using-loaddatafromnetwork-method

Answer (score 9):

If json data is of the form:

```
[ {...}, {...}, {...} ]
```

You got to use add another class say 'wrapper':

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ListDto extends ArrayList<GroupDto> {

    public ListDto() {
    }
}
```

And use this class while deserailizing. This approach worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify the `@JsonDeserialize(contentAs=GroupDto.class)` in your **setter**. Serialization is always on **get** desserialization is always on **set**, or if you prefer you can specify both on the field.

Documentation for [Serialize](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.2.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize.html) and [Deserialize](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.2.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonDeserialize.html)

Code sample:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonDeserialize;

public class JacksonDeserialize {

    public static class ModelClass {

        private String name;

        public ModelClass() {
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public ModelClass(final String name) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ModelClass [name=" + name + "]";
        }

    }

    public static class ListModelClass {

        private List<ModelClass> list;

        @JsonDeserialize(contentAs = ModelClass.class)
        public void setList(final List<ModelClass> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ListModelClass [list=" + list + "]";
        }

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue("{\"list\":[{\"name\":\"name1\"},{\"name\":\"name2\"}]}",
                ListModelClass.class));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on the getter/setter issue. I noticed in your example that you're qualifying the json array i.e. "{\" *list* \":...} Is it possible to deserialize *without* the qualification? If yes, how?

Comment: there iss no qualification, the magic is done in this case by `@JsonDeserialize` annotation. The property `contentAs` is to indicate that this is a collection and will be deserialized as `ModelClass`. If you want you could change the property name from `list` to something else. The name doesn't matter, what matters is the annotation.

Comment: I understand that the specific name is immaterial, but what does one do in the case where there is no name? In your example you're reading in `{"list": [...]}`, which has the key 'list', but what if there is no key (name) -- i.e. `[...]`?

Comment: Ah, there in lies the problem. The serialization/deserialization is handled by CXF, which calls a pre-defined `ObjectMapper`; consequently, I can't simply pass a `TypeReference` to a custom `ObjectMapper`, I have to rely on the pre-defined `ObjectMapper` and annotations.

Comment: Ok, which library are you using to integrate both?

Comment: There is no integration library; CXF allows one to specify a predefined handler.

Answer (score 0):

### Without using wrapper classes

Using Jackson's ObjectMapper

```
objectMapper.readValue();
```

Having data as follows...

```
[... , {YourObj} , {YourObj} , ... ]
```

You could do

```
YourObj[] yourObjArray = objectMapper.readValue(source, YourObj[].class);
```

If you then want to convert it to a List you could further do something like

```java
List<YourObj> yourObjList = Arrays.stream(yourObjArray).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

> Reference
> https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-collection-array