# Jackson - reading a JSON array with Robospice using loadDataFromNetwork() method

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, robospice

I'm trying to read JSON array, which has the following format: `[{"vehicle_id":"76","color":"red"},{"vehicle_id":"7","color":"blue"}]`, following Robospice's [Starter Guide](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/wiki/Starter-Guide).

**Vehicle.java**

```
public class Vehicle {
    @JsonProperty("vehicle_id")
    private int vehicleID;
    @JsonProperty("color")
    private String color;
}
```

(setters and getters follow)

**Class which is giving errors:
VehiclesRequest.class**

```
public class VehiclesRequest extends SpringAndroidSpiceRequest<Vehicle> {

    private static final String METHOD = "systemVehicles";

    public SystemVehiclesRequest() {
        super(Vehicle.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Vehicle[] loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
        return getRestTemplate().getForObject(
                FULL_URL,
                Vehicle[].class);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm overriding `loadDataFromNetwork()` method and then passing it to the `spiceManager.execute()` method inside my activity and reading data from the request using custom listener. **However I cannot return and array (I've tried with the `List<>` too) from `loadDataFromNetwork()`, what would be the best workaround here?** I know I could get the data in a different way but I want to still use my listener and be able to make `try` block that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding `Vehicles` class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Vehicles extends ArrayList<Vehicle> {

    public Vehicles() {
    }

}
```

and changing `loadDataFromNetwork()` method like that:

```
public Vehicles loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    return getRestTemplate().getForObject(
            FULL_URL,
            Vehicles.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that you should pass array type to super constructor:

```
public class VehiclesRequest extends SpringAndroidSpiceRequest<Vehicle[]> {

    private static final String METHOD = "systemVehicles";

    public SystemVehiclesRequest() {
        super(Vehicle[].class);
    }

    @Override
    public Vehicle[] loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
        return getRestTemplate().getForObject(
                FULL_URL,
                Vehicle[].class);
    }
}
```

And I think it looks much reasonable using an array type than creating a new class extending `ArrayList<Vehicle>` to get things work.